# Deleting certain instances of a class attribute

Tags: python

I am working with classes in Python for the first time and I need to loop through my class attributes and delete certain instances under certain conditions. The problem is that I cannot find any examples of deleting instances of certain attributes. To be a little more specific, my class is `phone_bills` and one of my attributes is `minutes_used` and the instance would be minutes used of a specific month. Well, sometimes I need to delete that one month or one instance.

I am starting to wonder if working with classes is wrong for this particular project.

Here is some of my code (where i make the class and then at the bottom where i try to deltete an instance.

```
class MeterBill:

'components of MeterBill'
def __init__(self,IDC,Name,StartD,End_D,Mdays,Cons):   #Name,StartD,End_D,Mdays,Cons):
      self.IDC = IDC       #idc
      self.Name= Name      #name
      self.StartD = StartD #startd
      self.End_D = End_D   #end_d
      self.Mdays = Mdays   #modays
      self.Cons = Cons    #cons

def __repr__(self):
      return repr((self.IDC,self.Name,self.StartD,self.End_D,self.Mdays,self.Cons))

  #there is some other code here to read in the data then

    e=len(bills); startlen=e;s=0
    row=0; daysthresh=38; count=0
    while count < startlen:
         for row in range(s,e):
            count = 1+ count
                                                                                       if bills[row-1].Mdays < daysthresh and bills[row-1].IDC==bills[row].IDC:    
           print bills[row-1],#row-1,meter[row-1]
           bills[row].Mdays = bills[row-1].Mdays+bills[row].Mdays
           bills[row].Cons  = bills[row-1].Cons+bills[row].Cons
           bills[row].StartD=bills[row-1].StartD
           #del mybills.minutes_used
           #bills=MeterBill()
           del bills[row-1].Cons
```

the last 3 lines is me trying to delte an  instance of my class at row-1 (using code from Peter Downs post). I want to delete this one line. I want to delete 1 single instance of each attribute that i defined.
so if I could get that del bill[row-1].cons   to work then i would do it for all the other attributes at row-1.
Note you have to scroll to the right ot see my if statement.

Comment: If "minutes_used > xyzzy" are you trying to delete the class or clear the attribute?

Comment: Working with classes is never wrong.  Your assumptions about classes, however, seem to be faulty.  There is no sensible reason to "remove an attribute".  Please provide some code to explain what you think you're doing.

Comment: _delete certain instances_, _deleting instances of certain attributes_, _delete that one month or one instance_ ... what is exactly what you want to delete?

Comment: @S.Lott has a good point. Why do you need to remove attributes? I threw up an alternative, but maybe you should change your whole approach.

Comment: I dont want to get rid of a whole attribute. Say the attribute is month so I might have Jan, Feb, March and different minutes used for each month. If one month meets certain conditions I will want to delete that month (that one instance is how i think you say it)and then i will also delete the instance of the minutes used that month as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am starting to wonder if working with classes is wrong for this
>   particular project.

I believe that they may be unnecessary. 
Instead of a class, try using dictionaries.
You could write a helper function to populate them, and it's very easy to remove a key from a dictionary.
The only reason to use a class is if you need instance methods - is that true?
Event then, you could rewrite them as regular functions.

```
def createPhoneBill(minutes_used):
    return {
        "minutes_used":minutes_used,
        # you could put more attributes here, just add them as arguments to the function
    }
```

As an added bonus, default values are much easier. Also, you get to use the `dictionary.get(attr_name, default_value)` function now, too.

Here's what deletion would look like:

*Deleting an attribute:*

```
mybills = createPhoneBill(5000):
if mybills["minutes_used"] > 2000:
    del mybills["minutes_used"]
```

*Deleting an 'instance':*

```
mybills = createPhoneBill(5000):
if mybills["minutes_used"] > 3000:
    del mybills
```

Comment: peter i added code where i attempted to use your: deleting an 'instance' code. Can you see if i am close to using it right?

Answer (score 4):

> I am starting to wonder if working with classes is wrong for this particular project.

No, certainly not, no worries :)

---

Lets say we have the following class:

```
class PhoneBills(object):
    def __init__(self, minutes_used):
        self.minutes_used = minutes_used
```

Then you can delete the attribute `minutes_used` simply by:

```
mybills = PhoneBills()
del mybills.minutes_used
```

Which would remove the attribute from your object `mybills`. All lookups would result in an exception. I'm not sure that this is what you want. Probably just setting `minutes_used` to `0` or `None` would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting means dereferencing the object, till its referencecounter reaches 0, so the garabage collector may free the allocated space for that particular object and effectivly destroying/deleting it.

What you want to do is set the appropriate attribute to None. By doing so, you reduce the refcounter by 1.

To illustrate what I mean, try the following:

```
import sys

ref = 'a Random object'
print sys.getrefcount(ref), id(ref)
newlist = [ref]
print sys.getrefcount(newlist[0]), id(newlist[0])
ref = None
print sys.getrefcount(newlist[0]), id(newlist[0])
newlist[0] = None
```

after the last line you have no reference to the underlying object, the refounter reaches 0 and the object gets collected by the garbage collector.

You may also use the del statement to express your intend clearly in your sourecode. e.g.: `del june` but then you also remove the identifier june from your namespace. Don't shoot the messanger! ;-)

Comment: it is `sys.getrefcount()`, not `sys.getrefcounter()`

Comment: I tied to do this del june suggestion in the code i added , but still some issues

Answer (score 1):

Using an object in this case isn't a bad idea, as others have pointed out.  However, you have to think about the problem just a little bit differently in order to get the best use of these objects.

---

If you have a `phone_bills` object, then we assume its only responsibility is to manage a phone bill.  It could be for a single month, it could be for an entire year - there's enough context in the object name that it could do both.

If it's managing a month-to-month bill, then what's required is, at the end of every month, the minutes used is *recalculated*, meaning that the value for the used minutes at this current point is reset, not deleted.

Now, unless your assignment specifically calls for you to delete the end-of-month total, then you're best served with resetting the value.  The way to do this with Python objects is simple:

```
phone_bills.minutes_used = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you don't delete objects--you simply remove any references towards them and allow the garbage collector to reclaim the memory they're holding.

Assigning `phone_bills_obj.minutes_used = None` would cause the garbage collector to remove the object referenced by `phone_bills_ojb.minutes_used`, in case the same object isn't being referenced anywhere else.

Comment: I have read what you said in the python docs and this is where i am confused. I dont want to delete every instance of minutes used and i don't want to set one instance to 0 either. I have minutes used for different months and will need to keep some of them. But, at certain times i need to delete one instance of minutes used. ( I may not want to keep the June month and I also don't want it set to 0, i just dont want it to not show up) Something like: delete(bills[row]).minutes  and  delete(bills[row]).months   Isnt there some Del function for once instance at a time?